# Wiping data on old j7 prime

Tags: recovery-mode, lock-screens, factory-reset, usb-debugging

My dads phone broked so he now is trying to use an old j7 prime he used before, the problem is the phone has lockscreen and he forgot the code, i tried entering in recovery mode but when i press Vol up+Home+Power it shows the SAMSUNG j7 prime boot logo and stays for a minute and then boot normally without booting in recovery mode, i tried booting in recovery with ADB but i cant activate usb debugging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't figure out how to enter recovery mode on Samsung A10s](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241291/cant-figure-out-how-to-enter-recovery-mode-on-samsung-a10s)

Comment: didnt worked :c

Comment: when i do vol up+power it boots normally, it doesnt boots in recovery mode

Comment: i will try with find my device but i doubt my dad remembers his account, theres no need for letting battery drain because im able to turn off the phone, the problem is i cant access recovery mode

Comment: i tried too and now im starting to think that maybe the problem is the home button is not working, is there anyway to access recovery mode without the home button?

Comment: you can buy JIG dongle to enter download mode and flash ROM